# How to write and read database from android apps

Tags: android, database, oracle, jsp, connection

Helo, im newbie at android programming. Right now im planning to do some kind of project. Says i have website, wrote in jsp, that contain product inventory and its detail, stored in database (oracle). 
my android app will have capability to scan qr code, which is contain key of certain product. users scan it and get the detail on their smartphone.
Im good at designing and coding, but i dont have any idea about this case. Do i have to use webview, or what?
Im sure you will enlight me on how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create webservice and connect Android to webservice

DB <--> WebService <--> Mobile Phone